# Can Dependency Management define version for Maven extension

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon, maven-extension

Have defined wagon-webdav-jackrabbit as an extension in Parent POM, the Parent POM makes use of Dependency Management POM.

Parent POM has extension defined for wagon-webdav-jackrabbit

```
<build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
</build>
```

DependencyManagement POM has version defined for wagon-webdav-jackrabbit

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Building the Parent POM pulls the latest version of wagon-webdav-jackrabbit i.e 3.3.1 and not the specified version i.e 2.10 provided in the Dependency Management POM.

In case of extension, the version specified in dependency management will not take effect ? Can Dependency Management define version for Maven extension ?

Comment: As you already wrote it does not so what kind of insight you would like to see?

Comment: @khmarbaise wanted to confirm if this is not the right way to define version for an extension.